# Update specific field of nested object in firestore document with angular fire

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I am currently creating a app with Angular and Firebase. Users can create rooms to which an unlimited number of players can join.
My data is stored in the firestore and i am using angular fire for querying and updating my data.

I am looking for a way to directly update a field in a nested object of a document with angular fire.

For example, this is my basic data model:

```js
export interface Room {
  infos: {
    players: {
        [key: string]: Player;
    };
  };
}
```

When a new player joins, i want to directly update the player field of the room, so no data can be lost, when multiple players join at the same time. I don't want to use `arrayUnion` so i am able to make updates to the players without the need to remove and add the array entry every time.

I already found a way to do this with the native firebase sdk:

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
  Firestore,
} from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import {
  doc,
  updateDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class FirestoreService {
  constructor(
    public firestore: Firestore
  ) {}

  updateField<S>(ref: string, fieldRef: string, data: S) {
    return updateDoc(doc(this.firestore, ref), {
      [fieldRef]: data
    });
  }
}
```

This approach worked perfectly fine but i could not achieve this with angular fire.
The problem is, that i want to update a field in a nested object. I know that angular fire uses a partial object to update documents. So i tried the following:

```js
constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore
  ) {}

updateField<S>(ref: string, data: S) {
    return this.afs.doc(`${ref}`).update(data);
}
```

```js
return this.firestoreService.updateField(
    `rooms/${room.id}`,
    {
        infos: {
            players: {
                ["playerId"]: newPlayer
            }
        }
    }
)
```

But that did not work. Everytime a player joined, the infos object was completely replaced with the one i sent.

Is there any way to achieve the same thing with angular fire or should i use the native sdk?

---

## Update

At first i used the working approach i showed first in my question. While testing with the firebase emulators everything worked fine. However, when switching to production mode, i got this error for every firestore thing i did:

```
FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore
```

I am pretty sure the problem is that i am mixing native Firebase SDK stuff with Angular Fire stuff.
I initialized the emulators in `app.module.ts` with Angular Fire:

```js
import {
  initializeApp,
  provideFirebaseApp,
} from "@angular/fire/app";
import {
  provideAnalytics,
  getAnalytics,
  ScreenTrackingService,
  UserTrackingService,
} from "@angular/fire/analytics";
import {
  provideFirestore,
  getFirestore,
} from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import {
  providePerformance,
  getPerformance,
} from "@angular/fire/performance";
import {
  connectFirestoreEmulator,
  enableIndexedDbPersistence,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire/compat";
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from "@angular/fire/compat/auth";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() =>
      initializeApp(environment.firebase)
    ),
    provideAnalytics(() => getAnalytics()),
    provideFirestore(() => {
      if (!environment.production) {
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        connectFirestoreEmulator(
          firestore,
          "localhost",
          8080
        );
        enableIndexedDbPersistence(firestore);
        return firestore;
      } else {
        getFirestore();
      }
    }),
    providePerformance(() => getPerformance()),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
      useClass: IonicRouteStrategy,
    },
    ScreenTrackingService,
    UserTrackingService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And my reusable firestore service looked like the following:

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
  collectionData,
  Firestore,
} from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import {
  addDoc,
  collection,
  CollectionReference,
  doc,
  DocumentData,
  updateDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class FirestoreService<D> {
  constructor(
    public firestore: Firestore
  ) {}

  docRef(ref: string) {
    return doc(this.firestore, ref);
  }

  colRef(
    ref: string
  ): CollectionReference<DocumentData> {
    return collection(this.firestore, ref);
  }

  getColWithIds$(ref: string) {
    return collectionData(this.colRef(ref), {
      idField: "id",
    }) as Observable<D[]>;
  }

  add(ref: string, data: D) {
    return addDoc(this.colRef(ref), {
      data,
    }).then((res) => {
      return {
        id: res.id,
        ...data,
      } as D;
    });
  }

  updateField<S>(ref: string, fieldRef: string, data: S) {
    return updateDoc(this.docRef(ref), {
      [fieldRef]: data
    });
  }
}
```

Note how i mixed Angular Fire and the Firebase SDK in the `colRef()` and `docRef()` functions, by importing `doc/collection` from `firebase/firestore` and `public firestore: Firestore` from `@angular/fire/firestore`.
That would be my best guess for the cause of the error. Is there a way to use both things?

Comment: There is no requirement to use AngularFire to write to the database. Its purpose is mostly about reading data, and since it wraps the Firebase SDK - the two interop seamlessly. Is there any specific reason why you can't just use the `updateDoc` call that you got working?

Comment: At first i used this approach. While testing with the firebase emulators everything worked fine. However, when switching to production mode, i got this error for every firestore thing i did: `FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore`
I thought, the problem came from mixing the angular fire stuff with the native Firebase SDK. So i decided to try and only use angular fire. I will update my question so maybe you can help me with that problem.

Comment: In that second part of your question, your `public firestore: Firestore` is a class from AngularFire, so you can't pass that to the regular JavaScript SDK. You should instead use `getFirestore` to get a reference to the same database that you can then pass to the JavaScript SDK.

Comment: Ah okay makes sense. But how can I get access to the argument that `getFirestore(app?: FirebaseApp)` needs in my firestore service?
I already initialized Firebase in `app.module.ts` with angular fire. Is it possible to initialize it again in my service to get the needed reference?